# Problem with structure of a semisimple ring theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, intuition

**Structure of semisimple ring (Wedderburn-Artin)** in *Rings and Categories of Modules - Frank W. Anderson,  Kent R. Fuller  (auth.)*

[image]

Proof:

[image]

Please explain that:

1. "Now $_RR$ is direct sum off these traces". It's OK!
2. "so (see 7) there is a finite set...". I read unit 7 and can't found that.
3. $T_i$ is simple left ideal of the ring $Tr_R(T_i)$
4. "Thus by 13.5 ..."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turning back to 9.12, you see

> **9.12 Proposition.** The socle of a left $R$-module $M$ is, as a left $R$-right $End(_RM)$-bimodule, a direct sum of its homogenous components.

In the discussion before this proposition, they give you the information to see that $Tr_R(T_i)$ is the homogenous component of $T_i$ in $M$. Explicitly, $Tr_R(T_i)=\sum \{_RS<_RR\mid _RS\cong _RT_i\}$.

For the case you are working on, $_RR=_RM$. Since $soc(_RR)=R$, Proposition 9.12 says for you "$_RR$ is a direct sum of $Tr_R(T_i)$".

Comment: Since $R$ is semisimple ring $\Longrightarrow _RR$ is semisimple $\Longrightarrow _RR = \oplus _I (T_i), T_i$ is simple $\Longrightarrow Tr_R (_RR) = Tr_R \oplus _I (T_i)$ and Proposition 9.11 says: $_RR = \sum _I (Tr_R (T_i))$. Since $_RR$ is finite generated so $_RR = \oplus _{i=1} ^n (Tr_R (T_i))$. Right?

Comment: Dear @Rachel : Well, 9.12 implies your last conclusion right away... are you trying to prove 9.12 from 9.11 now? Actually, I think A&F are laying on the terminology a little thick :) Many algebra books carry out this step this way: Show that the sum of mutually isomorphic left minimal ideals of a ring $R$ are an ideal of $R$ (called a homogeneous component for that isotype of ideal). Show that between different isotypes, the homogeneous components have intersection $\{0\}$, so their sum is direct. Finally, if $R$ is semisimple, the sum of all homogeneous components fills up $R$.

Comment: Thanks so much. But can u explain to me about my try above, is that ok? :)

Comment: Dear @Rachel : Sure, I can give it a shot. The first line is certainly true, but I don't feel like the reasoning after "$T_i$ is simple $\implies$..." is very focused. Starting from your first line,   think about grouping all the $T_i$ you wrote in $R\cong \oplus T_i$ by isotype. It turns out that the ones that are mutually isomorphic add up to an ideal. Instead of the $T_i$ then, you get $C_i=\oplus\{T_j\mid T_i\cong T_j\}$, and $\oplus C_i=R$. You're still working with the same direct sum, but now you collapsed groups of left ideals into ideals.

Comment: I mean, "$_RR= \oplus _I (T_i)$, where $T(i)$ is simple (semisimple module definition) $\Longrightarrow$ ..."

Comment: @Rachel Sure, one of the equivalent definitions of a semisimple ring is that it is a finite direct sum of simple left ideals.