# Semisimple ring problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that:

$R$ is a semisimple ring $\Longleftrightarrow$ Every right $R$-module is injective (projective)

My try: $R$ is semisimple ring $\Longleftrightarrow$ Every right $R$-module is semisimple $\Longleftrightarrow$ Every submodule is direct summand

Please explain that why since every submodule is direct summand then every $R$-module is injective (projective)?

Comment: If every submodule is a direct summand, then every short exact sequence splits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

Use these characterizations

- $E$ is injective iff every short exact sequence $0\to E\to B\to C\to 0$ splits for all $B,C$
- $P$ is projective iff every short exact sequence $0\to A \to B\to P\to 0$ splits for all $A,B$
- if $N<M$, then $0\to N \to M\to M/N\to 0$ splits iff $N$ is a summand of $M$.

Comment: So can I use Corollary 13.10 of Rings and Modules A&F? and use proposition: $E$ is injective module $\Longleftrightarrow$ every monomorphism $\phi : E \longrightarrow B$ splits.

Comment: Dear @Rachel It's just one idea. There are a lot of other approaches that would work too, but I'm not sure what you're comfortable with.

Comment: OK, thanks. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555507/problem-with-structure-of-a-semisimple-ring-theorem, u answered it before. I updated my question!