# Can you prove that over a division ring , every module is both projective and injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module

I have problem with this :
  over a division ring or a ring with identity every module is both projective and injective .
  Can you help me?
thank you .

Comment: 1: Proof is a noun, Prove is a verb, 2: what have you done so far?

Comment: I used Baer's Criterion theorem to prove , every module is injective @ZelosMalum

Comment: Have you shown that over a division ring every module is free? Then use the universal property of free modules.

Comment: I saw like this but for fields not for division ring

Answer (score 5):

I am just going to ignore the "or over a ring with identity" phrase because it is false and is a pretty weird thing to inject into an otherwise correct question.

There are a couple ways to approach this, depending on what you know

### Method 1

A division ring is a semisimple Artinian ring, and it [is well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566928/29335) that all modules over a semisimple Artinian ring are projective and injective.

### Method 2

In linear algebra, you prove that for a field $F$, every $F$ module is free, being a copy of some number of copies of the $F$ module $F$.

If you check the proofs, you will find out that it does not depend on commutativity at all: the same statement holds for division rings. This suffices to show all modules are projective.

Now, a division ring $D$ is certainly injective as a right module, and [since it is also a Noetherian ring, every direct sum of copies of $D$ is injective as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1222346/29335). This shows that all modules are injective.

Alternatively, you can apply Baer's criterion to any module since the right ideals of $D$ are trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much . Your explanation was so clear.@rschwieb

Comment: Sorry. I have problem with last part of your answer :   how can you conclude all modules are injective from last part of your proof?@rschwieb

Comment: @Narges In the first part, we proved that every right $D$ module is a direct sum of copies of $D$. Now, $D$ is an injective right $D$ module. So every right module is a direct sum of injective modules. Since $D$ is right Noetherian, we can conclude that such direct sums are injective as well. Ergo, all right $D$ modules are injective.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** *For a ring, the following conditions are equivalent:*
(a) *Every left $R$-module is injective*
(b) *Every left $R$-module is projective*

*Proof.* Suppose every left $R$-module is injective and consider a left module $M$, together with an epimorphism $F\to M$, with $F$ free. Then the kernel $K$ of this homomorphism, being injective, is a direct summand of $F$. So the exact sequence $0\to K\to F\to M\to 0$ splits and $M$ is a direct summand of $F$, hence projective.

Suppose every left $R$-module is projective and consider a left module $M$, together with an embedding $M\to E$, where $E$ is injective. Then $E/M$ is projective, so the exact sequence $0\to M\to E\to E/M\to 0$ splits and therefore $M$ is injective, being a direct summand of $E$. QED

For a division ring, it's trivial to verify Baer's criterion, because a division ring $D$ has only $\{0\}$ and $D$ as its left ideals.

---

Note. The two conditions in the theorem above are equivalent to $R$ being (left) semisimple. For a semisimple ring it's true that every module is a direct sum of simple modules. Over a division ring $D$ there's just one simple module, up to isomorphism, so every module is a direct summand of copies of $D$, in particular it is free.

This is a complicated way to show that the standard concepts of basis for vector spaces extend to (left) modules over a division ring, with no modification.